# How do we cancel the pending $http requests when the route changes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

We can abort the $timeout and $interval by using '$destroy' when the route changes. How can we abort the pending $http requests like $interval and $timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://blog.xebia.com/cancelling-http-requests-for-fun-and-profit/) article, it has some valuable information. Throughout the research I made, there is no magical solution unfortunately. You'll have to get your hands dirty and code a bit for some results.

Comment: Thanks again Peter